# Mailgun Reporting Functions

Tags: mailgun

Is there an open source project that deals with basic reporting functionality for Mailgun. All I want to do is download my permanent failures and export to a human readable file. Mailgun has an API that I can write code for that but I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

See [github.com/kehers/suet](http://github.com/kehers/suet) (disclaimer: I built this). It gives you a detailed analytics dashboard and breakdown of email performance, users, mails and feeds. You can also connect Slack and get complaints, bounces and failures send to a channel.

A managed version is available at [suet.co](https://suet.co/)